# what is a better way to define a fixed length 2d array similar to Python in C(without using dynamic memory allocation)?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I need to store a chess board into a 2d array which can be accessed like `chessBoard[row][column]`, similar to how Python does, and in the array, I'm storing single char elements, e.g. `'x'`.

There are two main concerns:

1. When I tried to declare the array like `char chessboard[10][10];`, I cannot find out a proper way to return it... Declared the function like `char **storeChessBoard(){}` whilst I was trying to do `return chessboard;`, it gives `returning ‘char (*)[10]’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘char **’` error.
2. I have tried to use struct to resolve the issue, but can't find a good way to do this. If this can be solved by creating a struct, could you give an example how to do it?

Comment: Aren't chessboards covered with 8x8 squares?  You can't return an array from a function.  You can return a pointer to some portion of the array.  Using `struct Board { char board[10][10]; /* or [8][8] */ };` you can pass that structure by value or reference to functions, and return it by value from functions.

Comment: Unless you really, really want to access the chessboard like that, it might be easier to flatten it into an 1D array and access it with `y * width + x` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning arrays from functions in C isn't possible, we can only return pointers. Returning a pointer to a 2D array from a function is a nightmare, the code turns alien-looking:

```
char (*func (void))[10][10];
```

I would not recommend to do that, but instead to pass the array both in and out of the function as a parameter:

```
void func (size_t rows, size_t cols, char chessboard[rows][cols]);
```

Comment: it could be improved a bit by using a `typedef char func_ret_t[10][10]` or by abusing `typeof` extension (a feature in C23). `typeof(char[10][10]) *func(void);`

Comment: @tstanisl Neither is an improvement. Hiding arrays behind typedef is almost as bad as hiding pointers. And for now, `typeof` is a non-standard extension. I don't know if the C2x one will be compatible with the current GNU extension either.